# Definition of the gamma function along different paths

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, gamma-function

Consider the gamma function $\Gamma(z)=\int_0^{\infty}x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx$, here $\Re(z)>0$.

Let $C$ be the path from $0$ to $ti$ and then from $ti$ to $\infty+ti$, where $t>0$ is a fixed number.

If I define $\Gamma_1(z)=\int_Cs^{z-1}e^{-s}ds$, here the $\log(s)$ is the continuation of the real $\log(x)$ on $\{x>0\}$ along the counterclockwise direction.

Then would the two function equals, or do they have any relations? Especially when $0<\Re(z)<1$.

Comment: By Cauchy's theorem, $\Gamma_1=\Gamma$ since your integrand is analytic when $s \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \left( { - \infty ,0} \right]$.

Comment: @Gary But at $s=0$ a 'pole' of integral may exsits, so I'm not sure.

Comment: You can argue that they coincide for $\Re z >1$ (the integrand will be continuous at $s=0$, so the (general) Cauchy theorem applies), and that they are both analytic for $\Re z>0$.

Comment: @Gary Great, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will coincide for ${\rm Re}\,z>0$ since the integral is convergent in this range of $z$.

Actually, we have the full course on complex analysis on edX.
https://www.edx.org/course/complex-analysis
The registration opened two days ago. It has a special chapter on analytic continuation with the help of contour deformation.

The welcome video on the course is here:
https://youtu.be/2aHEqRUYBUE